# NSString Manipulation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I would like to manipulate the NSString like as

(0) Likes (1). (see. (2))

(0) =  Raman

(1) =  You

(2) = ThisGift

to

Raman Likes You. (see. ThisGift)

I dont know what approch can solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance,
Regards

Venkat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6).

You use it like this:

```
NSString * source = @"(0) Likes (1). (see. (2))";
source = [source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(0)" withString:@"Raman"];
NSLog(@"%@", source);  //logs "Raman Likes (1). (see. (2))"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to change the template format, you can use [format strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH).

```
NSString *template1 = @"%1$@ Likes %2$@. (see. %3$@)",
         *template2 = @"%2$@ got a %3$@ from %1$@.";
NSString *msg1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:template1,@"Raman",@"You",@"ThisGift"],
         *msg2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:template2,@"Raman",@"You",@"ThisGift"];
```

or (if the format string can always depend on the arguments being in replacement order):

```
NSString *template = @"%@ Likes %@. (see. %@)";
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:template,@"Raman",@"You",@"ThisGift"];
```

Answer (score 0):

See [-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a)

```
NSString *foo = @"(0) likes (1). (see (2))";
NSString *bar;
bar = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(0)"
                                     withString:@"Raman"];
bar = [bar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(1)"
                                     withString:@"You"];
bar = [bar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(2)"
                                     withString:@"ThisGift"];
```